# What difference between the "set of ECMAScript execution contexts" and "execution context stack" in ECMAScript

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

In ecma262 we can find next part:

> An agent comprises a set of ECMAScript execution contexts, an
>   execution context stack, a running execution context, an Agent Record,
>   and an executing thread. Except for the executing thread, the
>   constituents of an agent belong exclusively to that agent.

What is the `set of ECMAScript execution contexts`? And what difference between `set of ECMAScript execution contexts` and `execution context stack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the set of ECMAScript execution contexts?

That means essentially "all execution contexts that exist".

> And what difference between set of ECMAScript execution contexts and execution context stack?

The stack is explicitly the stack of execution contexts that have been created as code is executed. The execution context stack has entries pushed and popped from it in many places throughout the spec as functions are entered and exited.

As an example of where this difference can be seem, a new execution context will be created for an async function when it initially runs, and then popped from the stack when the function returns or awaits something. After it is popped, it is not part of the stack anymore and the async function is suspended, but will still exist as long as the function is waiting for something else and could thus be pushed back onto the stack later, so would still be part of the "set of ECMAScript execution contexts".

Comment: I correctly understand that set of ECMAScript execution contexts is an entity that registers (holds) all execution contexts, regardless of what status they have. Whether pushed temporarily or held on the stack, or deleted permanently. I apologize if I am inaccurate in terminology.
P.S Nice to see you answering my questions =)

Comment: I don't think that description means that the agent explicitly has an array of all contexts that it could traverse, since it probably doesn't need that, but what it is saying is that conceptually all execution contexts are associated with exactly one agent.

Comment: It is logical! That is, the difference is that the stack contains execution contexts that will be executed in the order of the LIFO rule. And set of execution contexts shows execution contexts that exist and that can be pushed back to the stack of execution contexts. I am right?

Comment: loganfsmyth, please check inbox messages. I invited you into chat. I have global question about ECMAScript.

Comment: loganfsmyth, check out my new question, please. There, people remove the tag from `ecmascript-6` - which is understandable, but most likely you would not have seen this question without telling you this.